# iAd interstitial always fails with Ad inventory unavailable" iOS 8.4.1 only

Tags: ios8, iad, interstitial

I have implemented iAD interstitial adverts and everything works correctly in iOS 9 on the device. The advert will load and all delegate methods fire of correctly. Nicely filling the screen.

However running the exact same code on iOS 8.4.1 on a device results in the add always failing with the following error:

```
Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x1748666c0 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain}
```

Now just to point out i have set the app fill rate in the developer settings to 100% and have the exact settings between both my iOS9 and iOS 8 device. I've tried changing the device time (someone had recommended this) but no joy. Here's how i implement the advert:

```
//create the advert
interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc]init];
            interstitial.delegate = self;
            displayView.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;

// show the advert
 CGRect interstitialFrame = navigationView.view.bounds;
    interstitialFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    adView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:interstitialFrame];
    [navigationView.view addSubview:adView];

    //__weak __typeof__(id) weakSelfInterstitial = interstitial;
    [interstitial presentInView:adView];
```

One note on a very very rare occasion the advert will load, however instead of the familiar iAD test advert splash screen, the screen is actually black. Now tapping on the screen will correctly load and display the advert with a close button. But something seems odd here.

Comment: Please note the iAd is shutting down https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a So unless your app is already live and running ads you are probably wasting your time looking into iAd errors. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the info, however why would it display fine on an iOS 9 device?  I assumed they were just shutting down the campaigns but now the whole ad network is going, what a shame.

Comment: It is a shame, hopefully they will continue to allow alternatives.